# Partial transparency of fabric in EEVEE

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency

how to achieve the same effect of fabric translucency in EEVEE as in Cycles.

[image]

In case it is not clear: It is necessary that the light source partially shines through the material (fabric).
All the guides I found on the Internet referred exclusively to Cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a *Diffuse* or a *Principled BSDF* to a *Translucent* node with a *(Shader)* *Add Shader* node:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some optimization, but you'll achieve it.

Here is a way:

In the Eevee settings, you can change the *Blend* and *Shadow* mode to get good results:

[image]

Next, you have to enable *Screen Space Reflections* and *Subsurface Translusency* here:

[image]

Make sure the refraction depth is above 0m. Then, you also have to enable it here:

[image]

Try tweaking the settings to get your desired result.